# Python read binary: how to unpack a large number of numbers?

Tags: python

Basically I want to read a binary file contains a large number of doubles. Not sure how to achieve the following:

```
N=10000000
fin=open("sth.bin","rb")
data = struct.unpack('dddddd......',fin.read(8*N)) #of course not working, but this is what I want
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the file, unpacking chunks at a time:

```
with open("sth.bin", "rb") as f:
    numbers = [
        struct.unpack('d', chunk)[0]
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8), "")
    ]
```

There are a bunch of optimizations you could do here — reading larger chunks of the file at a time (4096 bytes is generally ideal) and creating a [compiled Struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.Struct) — but that's the general idea. If performance is especially important, you could also unpack multiple doubles at a time (ex, `struct.unpack('d' * 8, chunk)`) to reduce the number of function calls:

```
numbers = []
struct_4096 = struct.Struct("d" * 4096 / 8)
with open("sth.bin", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(4096)
        try:
            numbers.extend(struct_4096.unpack(chunk))
        except struct.error:
            numbers.extend(struct.unpack("d" * len(chunk) / 8))
```

Comment: I think you mean `c`hunk not hunk here David :)

Answer (score 3):

The format of struct support count, for example following code will unpack 100 doubles:

```
import struct
struct.unpack("100d", string)
```

if you are dealing with large number of doubles, I suggest you using numpy:

```
np.fromfile(f, dtype=float, count=100)
```

will create a 100 double array from the file.